# Find subsequence from array at every n interval

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I would like to find the sequence in a list of numbers where it returns the maximum sum. The restrictions are that it must be at every *n* interval. For example:

**n** = 4;
**A** = [1 4 3 2 9 8 7 6]

The optimal subsequence is therefore 4 + 8 = 12 at positions 1 & 5 (we assume position numbering starts at 0).

My idea: 
I know this is a dynamic programming problem. However, I'm not sure how to think about it in terms of a smaller problem. Hope this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't that just a matter of finding the largest of the `n` possible subsequences? Seems rather easy. Or are negative numbers allowed in the array? In this case it would get slightly more difficult.

Comment: @Henry I'm not sure what you mean. This problem requires you that, if you choose an index i, you can only sum the values at i, i+4, i+8....so on. Also, negative numbers are not considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the numbers are non negative, it is best to make the subsequence as long as possible to get the maximum sum. The restriction with the interval means, that there are just `n` possibilities to choose the starting index. In the example you get these four:

```
1 9
4 8
3 7
2 6
```

Calculate the sum for each and choose the largest.

Comment: The problem with this is that you brute-force your solution. I want to go about it via a dynamic programming way. The time-complexity isn't so bad when we consider a small array, but if we're talking about an array of 1 million numbers where n = 2, the solution becomes much more difficult to compute.

Comment: You have to look at each number at least once. What I did here, was looking at each number exactly once. This is the best you can achieve. One million numbers and interval 2 means you have to compute two sums with half a million numbers each. What's so difficult about it?

Comment: I see. I was not sure if dynamic programming was a better approach or if there was even one to begin with. I originally had this solution in mind but was not confident it would be efficient in terms of time complexity. Thank you!

Comment: Dynamic programming is only useful in situations where you can avoid repeated recalculation of subproblems by using it. This is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

You can look to the *remainder of the index of the elements by n* to divide the elements in subset of element distant n the one from another. Then summing all the elements of each subset, you can find the one that with the higher sum. 
The sequence (index in the original array, value) at this point can be easily found.
I mean something like this (pay attention at the indentation)

```
   n=lenght of the inteval;
   group[n]=[]
   sum[n]=[0,....,0];
   for i=0,...,array.lenght-1
      k=i%n;
      insert the i-th element of the array in group[k];
   for j=0,...,n-1
      sum[j]=sum of all element in group[j];
   max=0;
   for k=0,...,n-2
      if(sum[k]<sum[k+1])
        max=k+1;
   for u=0,...,group[max].lenght
      index=u*max;
      print (index, group[max][u])
```

I'm not sure this is the approach you are looking for, but maybe it can help you.